# Run method V/S start method, confusion

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some trouble understanding threads in Java so i searched up some answers on stack exchange and elsewhere. The summary of almost every answer was this:

`The start method makes sure the code runs in a new thread context.` 
***If you called run directly, then it would be like an ordinary method call and it would run in the context of the current thread instead of the new one.*** 
`The start method contains the special code to trigger the new thread; run obviously doesn't have that ability because you didn't include it when you wrote the run method.`

What is meant by the second line?
When i create an object of the class that extends the thread class and then i invoke the run() method using *that* object, how can it possibly trigger the *previous* thread?

I am creating a new object, isn't it supposed to create a new thread automatically when i invoke the run() method directly?

From what i understand from that answer, if i have 2 classes A and B both inheriting the thread class. First i use the start method on the object of class A and then i directly invoke the run method on the object of class B, it *would run in the context of the current thread*, that is, the thread of class A?

.

Note:- This *might* look like a duplicate question but i can assure you that i've done ample studies regarding this topic but i haven't been able to get satisfactory answers!

Comment: did you build yourself some code to try out stuff? how is your current knownledge how you would build it?

Comment: When you create a String and then call its length() method, does it start a new thread? No, it executes the length() method in the current thread. The exact same thing happens if you create a Thread object and call its run() method. It's executed in the current thread. The quote you posted never, ever talks about the *previous* thread. It talks about the *current* thread.

Comment: not pretty but may helps getting your idea: 
 https://puu.sh/wyKTZ/d44078c9d7.png 
 https://puu.sh/wyKV8/705bf86dc7.png  in order to make this class working you need to override the abstract run() class of runnable(this will be your function executed in a seperate thread) the rest of this class can like any other class contain other methods or fields

Comment: don't confuse the Java object `Thread` with system thread. When you create a Java `Thread` it is not creating/starting a system thread, only when you call `start()` a new system thread is created and started to execute the `run()` method. (if `run()` is called instead of `start()`, no system thread is created, it is executed in the same thread as the caller)

Comment: i think my confusion lies where @CarlosHeuberger has pointed out. So, when i create two objects of two different classes inheriting the Thread class, they will run on the same system thread if i invoke the `run()`  function directly but will run on two different system threads if i invoke the `start()` function?

Comment: Yes. Calling start() starts a thread of execution, which executes the Thread object's run() method. Not that you should not override Thread.run() anyway. Instead, you should define a Runnable, and pass it to the Thread constructor. Starting the thread will then execute the Runnable's run() method in another thread.

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw almost correct, `run()` of the two Threads will not necessarily run on the same thread, each will run on thread the calling method is running on - probably the same for both since they are both (probably) being called from the main thread - the one where the main method was started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am creating a new object, isn't it supposed to create a new thread automatically when i invoke the run() method directly?

No. You are just creating a new `Thread` object that *represents* a thread. The thread haven't been started yet, and calling `run` will obviously *not* start it. If you call `run`, *it will run on whatever thread that the calling code is running on.*

> From what i understand from that answer, if i have 2 classes A and B both inheriting the thread class. First i use the start method on the object of class A

Great, now we have started a thread using `aObject.start()`. However, the calling code is still running on the main thread. Only the stuff inside the `run` method of `A` is running on the new thread.

> and then i directly invoke the run method on the object of class B, it would run in the context of the current thread, that is, the thread of class A?

As I said before, the current thread is still the main thread, not the thread represented by the object of `A`. Calling `run` on the object of `B` would simply run whatever is in it on the main thread.

Comment: so, from what i understand from the comments on my question and your answer, there is a main "system thread" on which every other "sub-thread" will run if we directly use the `start()` method. If, however, we use the `run()` method for say, object B, then another system thread (other than that main system thread) will be created and that sub-thread of object B will run on the second system thread. Is that right?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw No! Calling `run` will run the code on the same thread as the caller! If you call `run` on the main thread, code will be run on the main thread. If you call it on some other thread, Thread X, the code will be run on Thread X. And there is no "another system thread".

Comment: just a quick question, is there a way i can visualise all this? i can not really understand the concept of thread.. i was thinking along the lines of cars moving on a highway in different lanes but i am not sure if i can think of it correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what tool you can use to visualise this, and I don't think highway is a good analogy. I think tree branches might be better. When you call run, you stay on the same tree branch and grow upwards. When you call start, a new branch grows out of the branch you were on. @TrafalgarLaw

Comment: perfect, gotcha! :)